# creating a firebase event listener using REST

Tags: python, rest, events, server, firebase

I am trying to implement a Firebase Server using [this Python library](http://ozgur.github.io/python-firebase/), and am having trouble understanding [Firebase's REST streaming API](https://www.firebase.com/docs/rest/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-rest-streaming), which seems to be what I need to use for my server. The only examples I can find are [here](https://github.com/firebase/EventSource-Examples/tree/master/python), and either I can't decipher it or it does not explain how to use the code in the way that I need.

What I am trying to do is create an event listener which will listen for any changes to or new children of a branch of my Firebase database, and make changes to a separate branch accordingly. This is how I have the same functionality implemented in JavaScript:

```
var sumVal = new Firebase("myProject.firebaseio.com/sum");
users.on("child_changed", function(snapshot) {
    var user = snapshot.val();
    var dataVal = user.data;
    var uid = snapshot.key();
    var url = "myProject.firebaseio.com/users/" + uid;
    var userID = new Firebase(url);
    var newSum = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < dataVal.length; i++) { 
        newSum = newSum + dataVal[i];
    }

    if(uid){
        sumVal.update({
            sum: newSum
            });
    }

});
```

It would be extremely helpful if someone could provide a brief example on how this kind of system would be implemented in Python, as I could then get a much better understanding of how the two languages "translate" to one another.

NOTE: Please do not just link me to resources I have already listed, as I have spent the past 2 days trying to figure them out and simply being told to look at them again will not help.

Update: If this can be done with polling instead of streaming, then I would be willing to use that instead.

Comment: You'll want to use the [REST streaming API](https://www.firebase.com/docs/rest/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-rest-streaming), which uses SSE to accomplish something similar to what the Firebase SDKs do. There's even a ppython example on Github](https://github.com/firebase/EventSource-Examples).

Comment: Like I said in the question, I'm aware of the streaming API, but based on the examples they give, I can't really make heads or tails of it. Also I still don't know how to do the first 2 preliminary steps; googling them just keeps leading me back to that same page.

Comment: The github repo I linked to has a complete working example. Did you try getting that to work? Where did you get stuck? What error message did you get?

Comment: The python examples run fine, but reading through them, I don't see the streaming format that is given in the API examples anywhere. Therefor I can't figure out what I need to do to implement my code, nor am I able to decipher which parts of the python example do what.

Comment: The client tutorials give pages of examples on how event listeners work and what their outcomes are, but the REST streaming tutorial is just one small section of the retrieving data page, and it doesn't explain how to implement it; it just gives the structure of sending events, which isn't even used anywhere in the Python code examples.